# php pthreads thread doesn't see external classes

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

So problem is that pthread's thread can't see some classes, or maybe I just don't know the proper way to load them. Here's the test code:

```
require_once('1/class.php');
require_once('1/geoip2.phar');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;


$t = new Test();
$t->start();
```

And thats a class.php:

```
require_once('geoip2.phar');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

class Test extends Thread{
    private $reader;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->reader = new Reader('C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\temp\\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
    }

    public function run(){

        //$reader = new Reader('C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\temp\\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
        //$ip = gethostbyname('');
        $record = $this->reader->country('127.0.0.1');
        //print_r($record);
        echo trim($record->country->name);
    }
}
```

And the error message is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'GeoIp2\Database\Reader' not found in C
\Users\bb\Desktop\temp\1\class.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Test->run()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\bb\Desktop\temp\1\class.php on line 12
```

So how can I add external classes to thread? Thanks!